# How do I find the coefficients of a two-sample T2 Hotelling Test?

Tags: hotelling-t2

Hi I am trying to figure out how to obtain the coefficients for the linear combination of variables determined by a Hotelling $T^2$ test.

I know that for the one sample case it is 
$a = S^{-1} \Delta $

where $\Delta =  (\overline{X} - \mu_o)$

But I am a bit lost trying to figure out the two sample case.

**More info**

A one sample Hotelling $T^2$ can be formulated as an optimization problem. This is, to find the linear combination $W = a^TX$ that maximizes $h^2(a) = \frac{Na^T(\overline{X}-\mu)(\overline{X}-\mu)^Ta}{a^TSa}$

Here $X$ is a multivariate sample, $\mu$ is the hypothesized mean and $S$ is the covariance matrix of the variables contained in X.

So basically the optimization problem consists in finding the vector $a$ which is the vector of coefficients.

Now my question is how do you obtain this vector for the two-sample case?

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling's_T-squared_distribution#Hotelling.27s_two-sample_T-squared_statistic) what you're looking for?

Comment: Not really. I am editing the question to provide more information.